# Remove null value from 2D array to calculate the number of its elements

Tags: java, null, multidimensional-array

I am  trying to calculate the number of elements in an uneven 2D array. If I try to print each element, it throws null exception.

1-How do I make it ignore the null entry?

2- How can I calculate the number of elements in this matrix to create a new array that equals the number of the elements in this matrix?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] mat2 = { {1, 2, 3},
    {4, 5},
    {6},
    null,
    {},
    {7,8}};

    System.out.println("rows " + mat2.length);

    for (int r = 0; r < mat2.length; r++) { 
        for (int c = 0; c < mat2[r].length; c++) {
            int numElements = mat2[r][c]; 
            System.out.println(numElements);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("cols " +mat2[0].length);

    //for (int[] row : mat2)
    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check it manually.

For example this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] mat2 = {{1, 2, 3},
    {4, 5},
    {6},
    null,
    {},
    {7, 8}};
    System.out.println("rows " + mat2.length);
    for (int r = 0; r < mat2.length; r++) {
        if (mat2[r] == null) {
            System.out.println("There is null");
        } else {
            for (int c = 0; c < mat2[r].length; c++) {
                int numElements = mat2[r][c];
                System.out.println(numElements);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("cols " + mat2[0].length);
}
```

Has this output :

```
rows 6
1
2
3
4
5
6
There is null
7
8
cols 3
```

Answer (score 0):

just check for null:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
            int[][] mat2 = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5 }, { 6 }, null, {}, { 7, 8 } };
            System.out.println("rows " + mat2.length);
            for (int r = 0; r < mat2.length; r++) {
                if (mat2[r] == null)
                    continue;

                for (int c = 0; c < mat2[r].length; c++) {
                    int numElements = mat2[r][c];
                    System.out.println(numElements);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("cols " + mat2[0].length);
            // for (int[] row : mat2)
            // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));



}
```

Comment: thanks! i was trying to do that but i stupidly put the null check in the second loop.

Comment: i did the same mistake first ;D